# Laravel - Many to Many Polymorphic Relation with Extra Fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I define a many to many polymorphic relation with extra fields?

I have three (or more, as it is a polymorphic relation) tables.

`tags table: id, name`

`tagged table: id, tag_id, taggable_id, taggable_type, user_id`

`posts table: id, record, timestamps`

`users table: id, name, email`

The `user_id` on the tagged table referes to the users table on column id.
In my Post model I have:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable','tagged');
}
```

and in my Tag model I have:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'taggable','tagged');
}
```

Then when I am try this in my controller:

```
$tag = new \App\Tag(
array(
    'tag'=>"someTag"
));
$tag->save()
$post = \App\Post::find($id);
$post->tags()->save($tag);
```

I get Integrity Constraint Violation for not having a user_id:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hb`.`tagged`, CONSTRAINT `tagged_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `tagged` (`tag_id`, `taggable_id`, `taggable_type`) values (26, 2, App\Resource)).
>   Which is somewhat expected, as I have never had the chance to define or declare the user_id field.

Also, I have tried withPivot() on tags relation as follows, to no avail:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable','tagged')->withPivot('user_id');
}
```

Comment: Tried withPivot()? The problem is that how can I assign the attribute. I have tried withPivot('user_id') and I still get an integrity constraint error when I pass an array that also contains the user_id to the create method. It doesn't put the user_id in its query.

Comment: `creating` has pretty much nothing to do with `withPivot`. So instead of the question you posted (read this http://xyproblem.info/) show what you're trying to do, what you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: Also, [duplicating your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496380/laravel-appending-extra-fields-before-saving-a-polymorphic-many-to-many-relati) won't help you...

Comment: @milz However, asking the question from a different point of may help!

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk: Here, I have laid the question out. Should I provide anymore details?

Comment: @CrackingTheCode You have the answer below, but really, read the XY problem site I linked before - your whole question could be squashed in one sentence: *I want to save ..., but when I do: **CODE**, then I get this error: **CODE** .*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like in the comment: `withPivot` has nothing to do with `saving/creating`. If you want to pass additional pivot data when `saving`, do this:

```
$post->tags()->save($tag, ['user_id' => $userId]);
```

Comment: would this also work when using `sync()` instead of `save()`?